# How to change dynamically UIWebView's height depending on HTML content?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have a simple nib with few buttons and `UIWebView` on which I want to display some HTML. I want to change the height in `UIWebView`  depending on HTML content. But I can't.

My nib look like this:
[My nib](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25549054/my_nib.png)

My `mainViewController.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ibecViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webV;

@end
```

I've used `sizeToFit`, but it doesn't work. My `mainViewController.m`:

```
#import "ibecViewController.h"

@interface ibecViewController ()

@end

@implementation ibecViewController
@synthesize webV;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *myHTML = @"<html><body><h1>Hello, world!</h1><p>Hello, world</p><p>Hello, world</p><p>Hello, world</p><p>Hello, world</p><p>Hello, world</p><p>Hello, world</p><p>Hello, world</p><p>Hello, world</p><p>Hello, world</p><p>Hello, world</p><p>Hello, world</p></body></html>";
    [webV loadHTMLString:myHTML baseURL:nil];

    [webV sizeToFit];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setWebV:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"123");
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"456");
}

@end
```

My second question: Why don't the methods `webViewDidStartLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad` work? Despite I have writen that my controller conforms to `UIWebViewDelegate`. I'm new in iOS. 
The height of the WebView doesn't change. And my application looks like this:
[My app](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25549054/iphone.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. In my `ibecViewController.m` I have written method

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[self webV] setDelegate:self];
}
```

And it works as delegate. My methods `webViewDidStartLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad` became working too. Then I implemented

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [webV sizeToFit];
}
```

Comment: I also saw a suggestion(don't remember where) that injecting JS for the onload event to notify back to obj-c work better, as , supposedly, webViewDidFinishLoad sometimes forgets to be fired. Not sure about the claims though, but they are sound. Better safe than sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer to First Question:

Try using `[webV setScalesPageToFit:YES];` function instead of `sizeToFit`. Html content will autoresize to webview size. I guess this function is only present in higher versions of ios.

Answer to Second Question:
You must delegate the webview object with the self object representing the view controller (`ibecviewcontroller`) inside which webview was defined. After delegation is done then you can probably make use of the delegate functions. If you are doing it through Xib then you should connect the webview object which is in this case `webV` with the Files Owner object or icon in IB.

Hope that helps..

Comment: Thank you for your answers. But the first not what I wanted. Using setScalesPageToFit:YES doesn't change my WebView, but changes HTML scale. And it became smaller. For the second I have written method (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[self webV] setDelegate:self];
} And - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[self webV] setDelegate:self];
}